# Python Pandas how to change row labels to first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this sample of a data frame showing population over the years.

[image]

I want to remove the row labels 'Country Code' altogether and have the next column, 'Country Name', as the row labels instead. How can I do this?

Let me know if you need more information or anything is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index('Country Name')
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple haha